# QTcpSocket problem

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

Writing a chat using Qt. Got a problem. My client's QTcpSocket remains in connecting state, but the server emits newConnection() signal. Network session is not required. Why is that? Here is some code:

```
ChatClient::ChatClient(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent) {
    tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;
    if (QNetworkConfigurationManager::NetworkSessionRequired
        & manager.capabilities()) {
        qDebug() << "Network session required";
    }
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()),
            this, SLOT(requestForID()));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(receiveMessage()));
    tcpSocket->connectToHost("192.168.0.100", PORT);
}

void ChatClient::requestForID() {
    qDebug() << "Connected, requesting for ID";
    QByteArray segment;
    QDataStream out(&segment, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_7);
    out << (quint16)0 << ID;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << (quint16)(segment.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    tcpSocket->write(segment);
}
```

requestForID() is never being executed

```
ChatServer::ChatServer(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent) {
    tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);
    if (!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, PORT)) {
        qDebug() << "Unable to start the server"
                 << tcpServer->errorString();
    }
    qDebug() << "Server port" << tcpServer->serverPort();
    connect(tcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()),
            this, SLOT(processConnection()));
}
void ChatServer::processConnection() {
    qDebug() << "Incoming connection";
    QTcpSocket *clientSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    /*connect(clientSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(readData()));
    readData(clientSocket);
    connect(clientSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),
            clientSocket, SLOT(deleteLater()));*/
    QByteArray segment;
    QDataStream out(&segment, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_7);
    out << (quint16)0 << (quint16)Message
        << "Successfully connected";
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << (quint16)(segment.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    clientSocket->write(segment);
    clientSocket->disconnectFromHost();
}
```

server displays incoming connection and the client does not emit connected remaining in connecting state, doesnt receive server message as well...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found the reason and a solution.

`connectToHost` may not be called in the contstructor of the main window directly. Why?

The reason is, that the main message loop is not running yet at this time. Internally `QAbstractSocketPrivate::fetchConnectionParameters()` gets never called and Qt Socket Timeout Timer thinks connection is never established.

The solution is either to call it "delayed" like in

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "OnDelayedConnect", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Or to call `waitForConnected()` after `connectToHost`